# Linux Cinnamon Mint 17.3 - panel applet broken

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

Ever since the update to 17.3, the update manager of cinnamon mint in the panel no longer shows a blue insert with the number of pending updates when an update is available, as 17.2 did.

I have manually checked for updates and found them, hence the request.

Occurs on two substantially different PCs; one was a complete install from scratch, another was an in place upgrade.

This suggestion did not work:

> Click on the Update Manager icon on your panel, then on "Edit"
>   followed by "Software sources" followed by "Maintenance". Then click
>   on "Fix MergeList problems". Finally, update the cache.

Nor did this:

> Have you adjusted the settings regarding the delay between refresh?
>   You may want to reduce the time between refresh. It may be too long.

or this:

> Do you have the software manager or synaptic open in the background?
>   Right click the tray icon and select Information:

There is no Information. There is About (which tells me it was written by update-manager@rotten-1.org, no release number, and that I may click on the applet to launch the Update Manager) and Remove this applet.

> Any hints there?
>   No hints, clues, or Norwegian Blues.

Another suggestion:

> Open the general settings of Cinnamon and disable the support for indicators
>   Probably you have to log off and back in.
>   The right click menu should now give the said (and additional) option.

Did **Preferences | System Settings | General | Miscellaneous options | Enable support for indicators** || and turned that off. Then, I rebooted. Right click menu unchanged. Applet appearance unchanged. Left-click and double-left-click do nothing.

How may I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different applets named Update Manager now. The applet with the icon of a brown cube is the useless one with an invalid address listed under About.

I reset the panel to the default design, which removed the useless applet, and brought back the functional Update Manager icon which shows the number of pending updates.